# Toggling Visibility of an Image

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, bufferedimage

I am trying to make a set of images appear for 5 seconds and then disappear, essentially a slideshow. This is the image class I'm using. I have the desired images in the same folder and pass the file name as a string when making an instance of the class. When I called the toggleVisible method, a frame shows up without an image. I am very unfamiliar with graphics and would appreciate any feedback, thanks.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;



public class Picture {

        private JFrame frame;
        private BufferedImage img;
        private ImageIcon icon;
        private JLabel lbl;
        private Boolean isVisible = false;

    public Picture(String s) throws IOException {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File(s));
        icon = new ImageIcon(img);
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setSize(300,200);
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        lbl = new JLabel();
        lbl.setIcon(icon);
        frame.add(lbl);
        frame.setVisible(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    public void toggleVisible(){
        isVisible = !isVisible;
        frame.setVisible(isVisible);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, in my simple testing, it works fine. Depending on the size of the image, there might be a delay in the rendering of the image.

Comment: A number of little things jump out at me.  Your basic requirement is for a `File` (or a `ImageIcon`), but you pass a `String` to `Picture`.  It would be better to change it so the constructor accepted only a `File` or `ImageIcon`, this clarifies the meaning of the value (what does `String` actually represent?) and a narrows some of the potential input values you might receive.

Comment: You seem to be creating a `JFrame` per image.  This is probably not the best choice, instead, you should start with a single `JFrame` and use a `CardLayout` to switch between the image, or better yet, load the image and "set" to the `JFrame` when you need it - just as an idea

Comment: The string contains the file name (ex. "picture.jpg"). I don't understand why the frame would show up empty when called from another class.

Comment: If the image isn't been loaded for some reason, your code will throw an `IOException`, make sure you're not suppressing the error

Comment: An IOException was being thrown and I was suppressing it. How would I go about fixing the root issue?

Comment: The likely cause is a "file not found" exception - this is why I suggested against passing a `String`.  Instead, pass a reference to the `File` object itself. Start by making sure that either the "picture" is located in the "working" directory of the App or your are using the fully qualified file name (including it's path)

Answer (score 0):

Is the image not showing up? you might want to assign a `JLabel` an `ImageIcon`:

```
ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("src/resources/resource.png");
JLabel l = new JLabel(i);
```

and you just set the JLabel visible or not visible. Also, set the bounds to roughly the size of the ImageIcon. If you want the ImageIcon centered on the JLabel, set the text alignment:

```
JLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
JLabel.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
```

If you set the bounds, with `JLabel.setBounds(x, y, width, height);` then you need to use `JPanel.setLayout(null);`

You also need a JPanel. you simply add a new JPanel:

```
JPanel back = new JPanel();
JFrame.add(back);
```

and then add all of the JLabels/Images (in your case). it should show up now, then comment under this and tell me the problem. Final code:

```
JPanel back = new JPanel();
frame.add(back);
back.setLayout(null);
ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("src/(whatever your resource file is called)/resource.png");
JLabel l = new JLabel(i);
l.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
back.add(l);
//this is optional, sets the image in the center of the JLabel:
l.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
l.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually, in your case, you just need to add the JLabel to a JPanel. Create a new JPanel, and then add the JLabel to the JPanel.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a little bit different approach for your question,

but you can accomplish this with overriding **paintComponent** method of the JPanel class in java.

First, You can have a canvas as a jpanel class.

This class take one parameter in which a path is an image directory.

```
class ImageCanvas extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private BufferedImage imageCandids[];
    private int imageLimitCount, imageCount;

    public ImageCanvas(String path) {
        File f = new File(path);
        String fileNames[] = f.list();
        imageCandids = new BufferedImage[fileNames.length];
        imageCount = imageLimitCount = fileNames.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++) {
            try {
                imageCandids[i] = ImageIO.read(new File(f.getPath() + File.separator + fileNames[i]));

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.drawImage(imageCandids[--imageCount], 0, 0, null);

        if(imageCount == 0) imageCount = imageLimitCount;
    }

}
```

It takes an array of **BufferedImage** class depends on the file list.

```
File f = new File(path);
String fileNames[] = f.list();
imageCandids = new BufferedImage[fileNames.length];
```

then, read each image with a read method of the ImageIO class in order to make a real BufferedImage object.

```
imageCandids[i] = ImageIO.read(new File(f.getPath() + File.separator + fileNames[i]));
```

You can refresh these images calling repaint method of the canvas object then a paintComponent method is executed .

Second, To make a silde show, I used a ToggleImageJob class inherited by a TimerTask class.

```
class ToggleImageJob extends TimerTask {

    public void run() {
        if (imageCanvas != null)
            imageCanvas.repaint();
    }
}
```

In a ToggleImageAction class, I show you how to run this job by a scheduleAtFixedRate method in a Timer class as follows;

```
private final class ToggleImageAction extends AbstractAction {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private ToggleImageJob toggleImageJob;
    private Timer  toggleImageScheduler = new Timer();
    private boolean isStart;


    private ToggleImageAction(final String name) {
        super(name);
        isStart = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {

        if(!isStart)
        {
            toggleImageJob = new ToggleImageJob();
            //every 5 seconds, 1 second delay
            toggleImageScheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(toggleImageJob, 1000, 5000);
            isStart = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isStart = false;
            toggleImageJob.cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

This action with a JButton is used when to start and stop this slide show by clicking it in turns.
A different image of the image buffer array will be showed up every 5 seconds, a unless user click the button again.

You can check the full source here.

```
package com.tobee.tests.swing;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ToggleImageWin extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final JPanel imageCanvas;

    class ToggleImageJob extends TimerTask {

        public void run() {
            if (imageCanvas != null)
                imageCanvas.repaint();
        }
    }

    class ImageCanvas extends JPanel {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private BufferedImage imageCandids[];
        private int imageLimitCount, imageCount;

        public ImageCanvas(String path) {
            File f = new File(path);
            String fileNames[] = f.list();
            imageCandids = new BufferedImage[fileNames.length];
            imageCount = imageLimitCount = fileNames.length;

            for (int i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++) {
                try {
                    imageCandids[i] = ImageIO.read(new File(f.getPath() + File.separator + fileNames[i]));

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            g.drawImage(imageCandids[--imageCount], 0, 0, null);

            if(imageCount == 0) imageCount = imageLimitCount;
        }

    }

    private final class ToggleImageAction extends AbstractAction {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private ToggleImageJob toggleImageJob;
        private Timer  toggleImageScheduler = new Timer();
        private boolean isStart;


        private ToggleImageAction(final String name) {
            super(name);
            isStart = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {

            if(!isStart)
            {
                toggleImageJob = new ToggleImageJob();
                toggleImageScheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(toggleImageJob, 1000, 5000);
                isStart = true;
            }
            else
            {
                isStart = false;
                toggleImageJob.cancel();
            }
        }
    }

    private static final String DIR_PATH = "resource/images/";

    public ToggleImageWin() {
        imageCanvas = new ImageCanvas(DIR_PATH);

        add(imageCanvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(new JButton(new ToggleImageAction("Toggle Images")), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new ToggleImageWin();
                frame.setTitle("Toggle Images");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                frame.setBounds(16, 16, 640, 480);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }
}
```

[image]

I hope this will help you.